# problems with setting to css attr field data-title, the id from javascript

Tags: html, css

I use a popup when take the mouse to icon, and it's working fine when the text was set static, but I need the text (my case: `data-title`) set id javascript. How can I do this?
P.S. I'm try to use `data-title-id`, but there don't give me any values.

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width:10px; float:left; padding-top:20px;">
<div class="photo4" data-title-id="time2"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/time.png" width="22" height="22px"></div>
</div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.photo4 {
    display: inline-block; 
    position: relative; 
}

.photo4:hover:after {
    display: block;
    content: attr(data-title); 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 120%; bottom: -250%; 
    z-index: 1; 
    background: #003399;
    font-family: Segoe UI; font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 13px; 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `content: attr(data-title-id);`

Comment: Why are you tagging this with `JavaScript`, if no JS seems to be involved anywhere?

Comment: If i'm use content: attr(data-title-id); i get nothing, no text are displayed.

Comment: Please help me in this example : http://jsfiddle.net/9oydvza0/           What shall i do that this variable takes value id time2

Comment: Sorry this link : http://jsfiddle.net/9oydvza0/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-*` attribute is named wrong in the CSS. It should be `content: attr(data-title-id);`.

Also note that [“In CSS 2.1, it is not possible to refer to attribute values for other elements than the subject of the selector.”](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content) and that [in CSS 2.1 the `attr()` function is limited to the `content` property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

Comment: If i'm use content: attr(data-title-id); i get nothing, no text are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your selector is correct, your HTML should look [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/9oydvza0/):

```
<div class="photo4" data-title-id="time2" data-title="YOUR TITLE HERE">
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/time.png" width="22" height="22px" />
</div>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: But need to set data-title text not "YOUR TITLE HERE", need text from javascript id

Comment: @user2884190 So you want the value `time2` in the blue box?

Comment: Please help me in this example :http://jsfiddle.net/9oydvza0/1/ What shall i do that this variable takes value id time2

Comment: As @feeela notes in his answer, that's not really possible, using just CSS.